# Why does the menu bar appear only when the window is maximized?

Tags: 16.04, debugging, menu-bar

My problem is that most graphical programs don't have a menu bar (File, Edit, View, etc.) when not on full screen (maximized) native built-in Ubuntu programs or third party stuff alike from VLC to calculators to native stuff like Nautilus

This problem (or default setting) existed since I first used Ubuntu 14.04 and now I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

If its a setting then how can I change it?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem. Can you post at least a screenshot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it from settings. Go to System settings -> Appearance -> Behavior.
There you will see an option "Show the menus for a window", and there are two choices. Either in the menu bar or in the window's title bar. Try both and use whichever you like.

PS: Please see the figure below.

[image]

Comment: lol thanks... cant get it though why they thought that the default setting should be "in the menu bar" I noticed this option as well but I thought "in the menu bar" meant to be each windoes places were the menubar should be (like in ms windows) and that the "in the window's titlebar" would show the menu above the title of the window :P silly me I didnt even try to mess with it.

Comment: No idea, but I prefer the menus "in the menu bar" instead of " windows title bar".